# Wildcard subdomains using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to change www.example.com/username to username.example.com. I've already set up Apache and now I'm stuck at this. In my userController I got this and it's working fine for www.example.com/username

```
if($validator->passes() && Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
    return Redirect::to(Auth::user()->username)->with('flash_notice', 'You have logged in successfully');
}
```

Now I got this in routes.php but does nothing. Thank you for your time.

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.example.com'), function()
{

Route::get('{account}', function($account, $id)
{
    $account = Input::get('username');
    $id = Input::get('id');
});

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You now want to route to the root of your domain, not to `'{account}'`. Just use a `/` as your route:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.example.com'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        $account = Input::get('username');
        $id = Input::get('id');
    });
});
```

Also, your redirect needs to redirect to the subdomain:

```
return Redirect::to('https://' . Auth::user()->username . '.example.com')
           ->with('flash_notice', 'You have logged in successfully');
```

Comment: What does "nothing" mean? What are you expecting it to do? You're not outputting anything from that route!

Comment: Well I'm expecting to get me to username.example.com from the login form at example.com/login